# Determining system configuration after rebuilding a Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 server that recently crashed and had to have Windows reinstalled. As part of this, Windows kindly created a Windows.Old directory with all of the previous configuration's files available for future reference.

Outside of third party logging and with only those files in Windows.Old available (so all of the C:\Windows\ files), is there any way to determine the hardware configuration as of that period of time? For instance, is there a way to see how much memory the OS saw as installed?

Comment: No, not automatically. This is one reason for the rise of tools like Puppet and Chef